# How can i put two textviews side by side with scrolling enabled?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Here's some part of my code but I don't want to use android:layout_width="240dp".
Please Help.There are two text views and both textViews are very long but they should not go outside of layouts and horizontal scrolling is enabled.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutSlide1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/option_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- OPtion 1 -->

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOptionA"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="A - Option A "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <!-- OPtion 2 -->

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOptionB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="B - Option B"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I made a photoshop image to show what i want;
there are two different scroll views.

[image: My problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulate your code according to this:

```
<LinearLayout>

  <HorizontalScrollView
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1">

      <LinearLayout>

         <TextView>
         </TextView>

     </LinearLayout>

  </HorizontalScrollView>


  <HorizontalScrollView
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1">

      <LinearLayout>

         <TextView>
         </TextView>

     </LinearLayout>

  </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code, i was tested this it working as you like.
[image]
**EDIT**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOptionA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:text="A - Option Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOptionB"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:text="B - Option Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sir, i meant no offense. I said that i got my answer from above source. Thanks for your time and support...